# Super-type for findViewById for Activity and View

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-view

You can invoke `findViewById` on `View` as well as `Activity`. Now I need to invoke it on both, depending on the cases. I want to avoid type checking or null checking and use either of them, but would like to cast the parameter to one type when passing it.

Is there something like a common interface to invike `findViewById`? Because from the source code it looks like it's just implemented for both, without connection to a super class or interface.

Comment: No, there is no common interface.  And I can't think of any reason you would need one.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Also, even if there is one that wouldn't prevent the need for null checking.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yeah, good point. Well I use a fragment to display content in a fragment, as well as an activity. Reusing the same layout. In each case I need to use either the fragment view or the activity to find the elements. But I guess there is a third way, just have to go back to the whiteboard.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in your `Activity` instead is getting decor view, on which you call `findViewById`.

```
public void myMethodRequiringView(View view) {
    view.findViewById(...);
}
```

in `Activity`:

```
myMethodRequiringView(getWindow().getDecorView());
```

in `Fragment`:

```
myMethodRequiringView(rootView);
```

If you look at the source of `Actvity` and `Window` Android classes, you will see this is exactly what is called in `Actviity.findViewById`.